# Unable to git push a submodule, but being able to pull it

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-submodules, git-push, git-pull

I am not very skilled in git. I have a git repo, say `mainrepo`, with a remote one on Bitbucket. `mainrepo` has a submodule in `mainrepo/modules/mymodule`.

I do not understand exactly what a submodules is, but, as I see, this sets the `.git` repo of the submodule inside `mainrepo/.git/modules/mymodule`.

In any case, I have two branches for `mainrepo` and `mymodule`, having the same names:

1. `develop`, which is present on remote
2. `feature`, which is **not** present on remote

For both `mainrepo` and `mymodule`, I have committed a modification on `feature`, fetched the latest modifications from `origin/develop` into `develop`, and merged those modifications in the `feature` branch.

I did it for both `mainrepo` and the submodule `mymodule` with no problem.

Now, I need to push those branches on remote, I am using Bitbucket. Note that on Bitbucket `mainrepo` and the `mymodule` are contained in two separated repositories. To do that I made

```
git push --set-upstream origin feature
```

This command works fine for `mainrepo`, but does not work for the submodule `mymodule`, I get the following error message

```
The requested repository either does not exist or you do not have access. If you believe this repository exists and you have access, make sure you're authenticated.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I tried to re-authenticate with SSH key, but nothing changed. I checked that the remote submodule repository exists, and it does. What it is confusing is that I can git pull, but not push.

Comment: run `git remote -vfrom the submodule directory, to check if push url is same as pull url

Comment: I discovered that the administrator of the submodule did not give me privileges to push to mymodule.
How do I mark this question as "solved"?

Comment: given the scope (it is unlikely that this question applies to someone else) you can simply delete your question. The other way is to answer it and mark your answer as "colved", but I think you have to gain a few StackOverflow points to be allowed to do that.